# How to use variables to query all records in table A that contain specified values in a column in linked table B?

Tags: sql, variables

Say we have two tables A and B, and A contains the foreign key B_id that links it to table B. Table B contains another column called fruits.

In SQL Server, what would be the best way to query all records in Table A for which the referenced records in Table B contain 'apple', 'orange', or 'pear' in the fruits column, using variables or a table variable?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable; this is SQL 101.

```
select * from a
inner join b
on a.b_id = b.id
where b.fruits in ('apple', 'orange', 'pear')
```

Comment: maybe he wants the list of fruits to be variable

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually trying to see the best way to store a large number of strings into a variable, as this is just a drastically simplified example. I see table variables being a preferred answer on similar questions, but if there are hundreds of strings to check for in the second table rather than three, would that require hundreds of insert statements?

Comment: Ah, that's more clear.  I would look at @Ala's answer in that case.